# Should inline undersink water filter be put before cold water input to undersink recirculating pump?

Tags: water, pump, filter

I have an older Laing hot water recirculating pump under the sink. I want to install a simple undercounter water filter for cold water at the sink. Should I install the filter before the pump or after the pump?

Comment: Do you want the hot water to be filtered also?

Comment: No, just the cold. The pump has a cold and cold out, hot in hot out where the water on the hot side goes below 85 it circulates it back into the cold line for reheat I connected the filter after the cold out but the faucet flow is very low - make claims small decrease in faucet flow.

Answer (score 1):

Put the filter after the pump so only water being used at the  faucet is filtered,since filter life is based on the amount of water running through it.